# Activity restarted when application is exited from unexception handler

Tags: android

In my application I use a global exception handler to avoid force close.But an activity is started after calling system.exit(0)....????

the logcat shown is:

```
07-18 12:41:12.569: WARN/Resources(8453): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f07000a}
07-18 12:41:14.648: INFO/ActivityManager(571): Displayed activity com.fss/.Loading: 2643 ms
07-18 12:41:14.689: INFO/System.out(8453): >>>>>>>>SentRequestBE
07-18 12:41:14.689: INFO/System.out(8453): >>>>>>>>StaticStore.dialog.getProgress()0==100
07-18 12:41:15.399: INFO/System.out(8453): >>>>>>>>SentRequestBE
07-18 12:41:15.429: INFO/System.out(8453): >>>>>>>>StaticStore.dialog.getProgress()20==100
07-18 12:41:16.288: DEBUG/SmsProvider(611): insert url=content://sms/inbox, match=2
07-18 12:41:16.510: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8453): GC freed 5512 objects / 258536 bytes in 745ms
07-18 12:41:16.640: INFO/System.out(8453): >>>>>>>>SentRequestBE
07-18 12:41:16.662: INFO/System.out(8453): >>>>>>>>StaticStore.dialog.getProgress()40==100
07-18 12:41:16.688: INFO/System.out(8453): >>>>>>>null
07-18 12:41:16.739: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8453): Shutting down VM
07-18 12:41:16.739: WARN/dalvikvm(8453): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
07-18 12:41:16.799: INFO/System.out(8453): ***************************EXception Ctached here********************
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.fss.SMSRecieve: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453): --------- Stack trace ---------
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2417)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:112)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1741)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453): -------------------------------
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453): --------- Cause ---------
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     com.fss.SMSRecieve.onReceive(SMSRecieve.java:26)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2408)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:112)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1741)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
07-18 12:41:16.919: ERROR/Report ::(8453):     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 12:41:16.939: INFO/System.out(8453): *************finally block enetered
07-18 12:41:16.979: INFO/NotificationService(571): enqueueToast pkg=com.fss callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@4381ced0 duration=1
07-18 12:41:17.018: INFO/AndroidRuntime(8453): AndroidRuntime onExit calling exit(0)
07-18 12:41:17.029: ERROR/JavaBinder(8453): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
07-18 12:41:17.049: ERROR/JavaBinder(8453): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
07-18 12:41:17.148: INFO/ActivityManager(571): Process com.fss (pid 8453) has died.
07-18 12:41:17.188: INFO/WindowManager(571): WIN DEATH: Window{43721d70 com.fss/com.fss.DynamicCanvas paused=false}
07-18 12:41:17.198: INFO/WindowManager(571): WIN DEATH: Window{43733cf8 com.fss/com.fss.ListSelection paused=false}
07-18 12:41:17.198: INFO/WindowManager(571): WIN DEATH: Window{437ba200 com.fss/com.fss.DynamicCanvas paused=false}
07-18 12:41:17.210: INFO/WindowManager(571): WIN DEATH: Window{43718e10 com.fss/com.fss.Loading paused=false}
07-18 12:41:17.210: INFO/WindowManager(571): WIN DEATH: Window{43744eb8 com.fss/com.fss.Loading paused=false}
07-18 12:41:17.509: INFO/ActivityManager(571): Start proc com.fss for activity com.fss/.DynamicCanvas: pid=8468 uid=10019 gids={3003}
07-18 12:41:17.958: INFO/jdwp(8468): received file descriptor 20 from ADB
07-18 12:41:18.189: WARN/System.err(8468): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
07-18 12:41:18.219: WARN/System.err(8468): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
07-18 12:41:19.710: INFO/ActivityManager(571): Starting activity: Intent { flags=0x24000000 comp={com.fss/com.fss.SplashScreen} (has extras) }
07-18 12:41:19.810: INFO/System.out(8468): Dynamic Canvas......
07-18 12:41:20.010: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>>5
07-18 12:41:20.020: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>> M-CONNECT  Login
07-18 12:41:20.030: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>>APUM
07-18 12:41:20.039: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>>Enter password
07-18 12:41:20.049: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>>4-6-N-Y-Y
07-18 12:41:20.079: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>>1
07-18 12:41:20.089: INFO/System.out(8468): temp >>>>> 1 4-6-N-Y-Y
07-18 12:41:20.489: WARN/NotificationService(571): Object died trying to hide notification android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@4381ced0 in package com.fss
07-18 12:41:20.499: WARN/ActivityManager(571): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{437a8b80 {com.fss/com.fss.DynamicCanvas}}
07-18 12:41:20.509: WARN/ActivityManager(571): setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 8453
07-18 12:41:20.970: INFO/ActivityManager(571): moveTaskToBack: 50
07-18 12:41:21.699: WARN/InputManagerService(571): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 8453 uid 10019
07-18 12:41:22.049: WARN/ActivityManager(571): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-18 12:41:25.041: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>>>>>>>>>OnCreateMethod
07-18 12:41:25.359: INFO/System.out(8468): >>>>>>>>>>>>DBNAME/data/data/com.fss/databases/MPAY_444444
07-18 12:41:25.369: ERROR/Database(8468): Failure 1 (table MiscDetails0029 already exists) on 0x1acf30 when preparing 'create table MiscDetails0029 (id integer primary key not null,table_row_one text);'.
07-18 12:41:25.388: WARN/System.err(8468): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MiscDetails0029 already exists: create table MiscDetails0029 (id integer primary key not null,table_row_one text);
07-18 12:41:25.408: WARN/System.err(8468):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
07-18 12:41:25.430: WARN/System.err(8468):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1496)
07-18 12:41:25.438: WARN/System.err(8468):     at com.fss.RmsStore$CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(RmsStore.java:240)
07-18 12:41:25.448: WARN/System.err(8468):     at com.fss.RmsStore.<init>(RmsStore.java:48)
07-18 12:41:25.489: WARN/System.err(8468):     at com.fss.SplashScreen.startApp(SplashScreen.java:72)
07-18 12:41:25.489: WARN/System.err(8468):     at com.fss.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:53)
07-18 12:41:25.608: INFO/System.out(8468): ::::::::::::::::::SataticStore.NO ON ACC6
07-18 12:41:25.628: INFO/System.out(8468): ::::::::::acountNumbers0
07-18 12:41:25.672: INFO/System.out(8468): ::::::::::acountNumbers0
07-18 12:41:25.688: INFO/System.out(8468): ::::::::::acountNumbers0
07-18 12:41:25.699: INFO/System.out(8468): ::::::::::acountNumbers0
07-18 12:41:25.699: INFO/System.out(8468): ::::::::::acountNumbers0
07-18 12:41:25.718: INFO/System.out(8468): ::::::::::acountNumbers0
07-18 12:41:25.768: INFO/ActivityManager(571): Starting activity: Intent { comp={com.fss/com.fss.DynamicCanvas} }
07-18 12:41:25.778: WARN/ActivityManager(571): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { comp={com.fss/com.fss.DynamicCanvas} }
07-18 12:41:26.969: INFO/ActivityManager(571): Displayed activity com.fss/.DynamicCanvas: 9671 ms
07-18 12:41:27.670: WARN/NotificationService(571): STOP command without a player
07-18 12:41:29.460: INFO/ActivityManager(571): Stopping service: com.android.mms/.transaction.SmsReceiverService
07-18 12:41:30.088: DEBUG/ActivityManager(571): checkComponentPermission() adjusting {pid,uid} to {542,1013}
07-18 12:41:30.239: DEBUG/ActivityManager(571): checkComponentPermission() adjusting {pid,uid} to {542,1013}
07-18 12:41:30.429: DEBUG/ActivityManager(571): checkComponentPermission() adjusting {pid,uid} to {542,1013}
07-18 12:41:30.628: DEBUG/ActivityManager(571): checkComponentPermission() adjusting {pid,uid} to {542,1013}
07-18 12:41:30.769: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(542): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
07-18 12:41:30.799: ERROR/MediaPlayer(571): Unable to to create media player
07-18 12:41:30.839: WARN/NotificationService(571): error loading sound for content://settings/system/notification_sound
07-18 12:41:30.839: WARN/NotificationService(571): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
07-18 12:41:30.839: WARN/NotificationService(571):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
07-18 12:41:30.839: WARN/NotificationService(571):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:610)
07-18 12:41:30.839: WARN/NotificationService(571):     at android.media.AsyncPlayer$Thread.run(AsyncPlayer.java:76)
07-18 12:41:32.818: DEBUG/dalvikvm(658): GC freed 687 objects / 28744 bytes in 537ms
07-18 12:41:37.668: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7930): GC freed 1122 objects / 53896 bytes in 377ms
07-18 12:41:42.769: DEBUG/dalvikvm(611): GC freed 804 objects / 39568 bytes in 476ms
07-18 12:41:48.278: DEBUG/dalvikvm(613): GC freed 445 objects / 21192 bytes in 495ms
```

i attached the exception handler also....

```
package com.fss;



import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TopExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler   {

private Context context;
//private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;



    public TopExceptionHandler(Context context) {


StaticStore.defaultHandler = Thread
.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
this.context=context;






    }






      public void uncaughtException(Thread t,final Throwable e)

    {
         StaticStore.mfs=true;
        try{
         new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();  


            Toast.makeText(context, "TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


//              context.startActivity(intent);
            //



            //System.exit(0);//If you want to restart activity and want to kill after crash.s
                Looper.loop();

            }
        }.start();

        System.out.println("***************************EXception Ctached here********************");

        StackTraceElement[] arr = e.getStackTrace();

        String report = e.toString()+"\n\n";

        report += "--------- Stack trace ---------\n\n";

        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)

        {

        report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";

        }

        report += "-------------------------------\n\n";




        // If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside

        // AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause



        report += "--------- Cause ---------\n\n";




        Throwable cause = e.getCause();

        if(cause != null) {

        report += cause.toString() + "\n\n";

        arr = cause.getStackTrace();

        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)

        {

        report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";

        }

        }


        Log.e("Report ::",report);



    }


        catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              StaticStore.index=0;
              System.out.println("*************finally block enetered");
              StaticStore.dialog.dismiss();

//            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
//            myIntent.setClassName("com.fss","com.fss.DynamicCanvas");
//              myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
//              myIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
//              context.startActivity(myIntent);
//            System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
 System.exit(0);
//System.out.println("after sys exit");
//  defaultHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);

          }
 //   throw new RuntimeException("You just caught me..");
    }


}
```

Comment: com.fss.SMSRecieve.onReceive(SMSRecieve.java:26)
Better check on this line.... something is null that should have some value

Comment: yes....the exception is catched in uncaught exception handler and i try to exit the application. but one of the activity in my application( DynamicCanvas activity) is restarted... how to avoid it or please let me know the reason for that???????

Comment: @vinith Can you please try to format your code snippet to make it readable? It's a bit of a mess. And you should also remove all the commented out code if it's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly belated answer, but... In my case this occurs only on few devices, for example on Samsung Nexus 7. To avoid this annoying restarts i remember current activity in static variable and call `finish()` before `System.exit`:

```
// base class for all activities in my application
class BaseActivity extends Activity {
  private static BaseActivity sCurrentActivity = null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    sCurrentActivity = this;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    sCurrentActivity = this;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sCurrentActivity = this;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sCurrentActivity = null;
  }    

  public static System_exit( int exitCode ) {
    if ( null != sCurrentActivity ) {
      sCurrentActivity.finish();
      sCurrentActivity = null;
    }
    System.exit( exitCode );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this post - I've been trying to understand why a very small number of my users where having issues and this was the solution. +1 !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! That worked - BUT: You must finish your main activity, it doesn't work if you finish some other.
And here is some enhancement: If you ever want a static reference to an activity, you better use a weak reference and a static getter, instead of a strong reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static WeakReference<MainActivity> sharedActivity = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public static MainActivity sharedActivity() {
        try {
            return sharedActivity.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The WeakReference won't prevent the garbage collector from GC'ing the activity. If it was collected, the return value of the WeakReference will be null, else the activity object is being returned. It eases your code and prevents you from accessing a finished activity.